# Could not create a service principal with the right permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, userprincipal, azure-aks

I'm trying to run command:

```
az acs create --orchestrator-type kubernetes --resource-group myResourceGroup --agent-count 1 --name  myK8SCluster
--generate-ssh-keys
```

Which should generate principal and then kubernetes cluster.

But there is error:

```
Could not create a service principal with the right permissions. Are you an Owner on this project? Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 1e8e87ee-f01e-4394-8356-cc4956b44b5e. {   "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The Service Principal in ServicePrincipalProfile could not be validated. Please see https://aka.ms/acs-sp-help for more details. (The client 'ffc0ce03-2ba5-46e7-b0dd-99a7980da24b' with object id 'ffc0ce03-2ba5-46e7-b0dd-99a7980da24b' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read' over scope '/subscriptions/b9a29aba-5bcd-45dd-99e5-8971de90d595/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Authorization'.)" } }
```

I have administrator role for my azure account, my directory role is Global Administrator and I'm the only person using this azure account.

I have trying deleting contents of .azure folder to no avail. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login account should has `Owner` or `Contributor` role for your subscription.

You could check it on Azure Portal.

[image]

Also, you could give sp   myK8sCluster  `Contributor` role and check again.

Comment: It seems I'm owner (and Service Administrator):

http://www.screenshot.link/upload/up/bfj.png

So I should be able to just use --generate-ssh-keys.

Comment: You use this account `iniside@live.com` to login your Azure account?

Comment: Yes. That's my primary account. It's under Visual Studio Dev Essentials subscription.

Comment: Could you see sp `myK8SCluster` in subscription?

Comment: Also, your user has `Global Administrator` permission in your AD. Like this screenshot?  https://imgur.com/a/EXA16

Comment: Subscriptions -> Visual Studio Dev Essentials -> IAM -> Add.
There is only one user (me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163305/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-lukasz-baran).

Comment: I'm getting the same error and can't get it working following the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163305/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-lukasz-baran). I am global admin and can't get `--generate-ssh-keys` to create the correct service principal

Comment: Your account is a Microsoft account, you need create an Azure AD account firstly,